# Generating random numbers in a file, and calling them from the file, then printing them out

Tags: c++, random, ifstream, ofstream

I'm trying to create a file that generates random numbers, then I want the program to call those random numbers and print them out. 1st; the srand
(time(NULL)) function is giving me an error, 2nd; i want to check wether the loop and the formula i used to get random numbers are correct.

Thanks.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
int rand(int x);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("fileTest.txt");

    int i;
    for (i =0; i<23; i++)
    {
        outputFile << rand(i) <<endl;
    }

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open ("fileTest.txt");

    int ranNum[i];
    for (int i = 190; i <= 270; i++)
    {
        ranNum[i] = (rand() % (270-190+1)+ 190);
        inputFile>> ranNum[i];
        cout<<ranNum [i]<<" "<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're saying. Files don't generate anything. They store data. Also your program doesn't call a number. It can call a function, though. Can you show the entire error message that you received on the call to `srand()`? (Please copy and paste the *exact* text here.)

Comment: When you write code, it's best to implement new functionality *in isolation* as much as possible. You're having trouble generating random numbers, so write a program that generates one random number and prints it out. Get that working perfectly before trying to dovetail it with any other code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <time.h>
#include <limits>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void generate_random_file(int size_of_array = 100) {
    ofstream fout; // open the stream
    fout.open("data_" + std::to_string(size_of_array) + ".txt");  // open the file
    if (!fout.is_open())
        cout << "Error: cannot open the file!\n";
    else
    {
        srand(time(0));
        int min = 0;//numeric_limits<int>::min();
        int max = 100;//numeric_limits<int>::max();

        int buf;
        for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++)
        {
            buf = min + rand() % (min - max + 1);
            fout << buf << " ";
        }
        fout << endl;
    }
    fout.close(); // close the file
}


int main()
{
    generate_random_file();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One should not recommend arcane `rand` in C++ when we have `<random>` library with modern and safe generators.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your goal is to generate set of random numbers and write them into file. Using your base code below you'll find working version. Please note some comments:

1. `int rand(int x);` This is a declaration, you cannot leave it as it
   is, also there is proper implementation of this function in one of
   the libraries you included.
2. Using `srand` before `rand` is
   recommended to initialize pseudo-random value generator. You are
   trying to use `srand(time(NULL))` which in every execution initializes
   with different
   value. If you use static value, i.e. `srand(0)` you get the same
   random sequence each time.
3. Also I assume you don't need to read from file, so following code
   generates array of random integers, prints them and save into file.
4. At the end of writing into file/stream you need to close this file
   `outputFile.close()`.
5. `cin.get()` gives you a 'pause' you are looking for, just press 
   to exit from program.

If you are willing to go deeper into C++ [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/?kw=rand) you have some handy resource.

Here is a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("fileTest.txt");

    srand(time(NULL));

    int range = 270 - 190;
    int ranNum[range];

    for (int i = 0; i <= range; i++)
    {
        ranNum[i] = 190 + 1 + rand () % range;
        cout << ranNum[i] << " " << endl;
    }

    outputFile.close();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an online compiler with [ready program](https://onlinegdb.com/H1_sPSY2z)